# Yeoman - Current best way to use it with AngularJS & Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, yeoman

**I am using Yeoman 1.0 beta and not interested in the express-stack branch.** What, then, is the recommended/best way to use Yeoman to scaffold an Angular project within Express?

I tried running `yo angular --minsafe` in the root directory of the Express project (where `app.js` and `package.json` are), but Yeoman was trying to override `package.json`, and the Angular files didn't go into the `public` subdirectory properly. Also I am not sure if I can just go manually moving the Angular files around without breaking Bower and Grunt functionalities.

Would be great to have some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This project seems to cover all of the requirements (and even has optional support for MongoDB): https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

I've just tried it locally and it works:

```
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack

yo angular-fullstack [appname]
```

See the GitHub page for more info.

Answer (score 4):

If you install Angular first through Bower, then add Express to `package.json` and run `npm install` - you'll have an Express server fire-up the `/dist` directory. (Edit `app.js` to route to `/dist` and let angular handle routing)

See this SO question for more information: [Yeoman inside ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106248/yeoman-inside-expressjs)

Comment: Guess this is the best we can get till the express-stack branch stabilizes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a comparison of alternatives for starting an AngularJS app.  Several of them involve Express too.

http://dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/

Answer (score -1):

After reading MANY blogs and answers, I managed to get it all working...
Check out this repo: https://github.com/malixsys/malix-yae

- When changes are made to html/server or lib, the server is restarted and the page should refresh
- When changes are made to HTML or JS files under html/client, the server is not restarted but the page should refresh
- When changes are made to CSS files under html/client, the new stylesheet should be injected directly without refreshing